# Manipulate members of vector in class

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I am getting started on writing classes and have the following question.
Suppose I have the following class:

```
class foo
{
private:
    int bar;
public:
    foo(int bar): bar(bar){}
    void set_bar(int ubar){bar=ubar;}
    int get_bar(){return bar;}
};
```

Now I want to write a class that contains instances of `foo`.

```
class foo_cont
{
private:
    vector<foo> foo_vec;
public:
    foo_cont(){}
    void add_element(foo f1){foo_vec.push_back(f1);}
};
```

Lets say I make an instace of `foo_cont f1;` and fill `foo_vec`it with instances of `foo`. How do I modify the elements of `foo_vec` with `set_bar()`?

Edit:
Since I am quite new to stack overflow this might be a really stupid question but why am I getting downvotes?

Comment: The `vector` in `foo_count` has a `bar` not a `foo`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Are you asking us how to call functions on elements contained within a vector?

Comment: Use index: `foo_vec[i].set_bar(0);`. And it's not good design at all.

Comment: can I really do that even though foo_vec is private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define `operator []` for class `foo_cont`. For example

```
class foo_cont
{
private:
vector<bar> foo_vec;
public:
    // ...
    bar & operator []( size_t i )
    {
        return foo_vec[i];
    }   
    const bar & operator []( size_t i ) const
    {
        return foo_vec[i];
    }   
};
```

For example

```
for_cont[i].set_bar( 10 );
```

In any case you need to provide accessors for the elements of the vector if you are going to change them outside the class scope.

Comment: ok if my instance of for_cont is called f1 I could do f1[i].set_bar(10)? Do I need to override the [] operator twice? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @PtK The second operator is needed when a constant object or a constant reference to an object is used. For example if you have a general function f( const foo_cont &c ); when within the function you may use only the second overload of the operator that is designed for constant objects.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I modify the elements of foo_vec with set_bar()?

**Inside the class `foo_cont`**

If you want to call `set_bar()` on the first element of the vector in `foo_cont`, you use:

```
foo_vec[0].set_bar(10);
```

If you want to call `set_bar()` on the `n`-th (by index) element of the vector in `foo_cont`, you use:

```
foo_vec[n].set_bar(10);
```

**By users of the class**

You can provide access to the `n`-th element of `foo_vec` through operator functions or by providing an accessor function to the vector itself.

```
bar& operator[]( size_t i )
{
    return foo_vec[i];
}   
bar const& operator[]( size_t i ) const
{
    return foo_vec[i];
}
```

and use it as:

```
foo_cont f1;
f1.add_element(10);
int a = f1[0].get_bar();
```

or

```
std::vector<foo>& get_foo_vector()
{
   return foo_vec;
}

std::vector<foo> const& get_foo_vector() const
{
   return foo_vec;
}
```

and use it as:

```
foo_cont f1;
f1.add_element(10);
int a = f1.get_foo_vector()[0].get_bar();
```

Comment: I believe OP is asking specifically about doing it through a `foo_cont` public API. See Vlad from Moscow's answer.

Comment: In case I didn't ask the question the right way, I want to have an instance of foo_cont in my main how can I access foo_vec even though it is a private member of the instance of foo_cont?